# Synchronize Oracle 11g xe database on azure vm with xe database on localhost

Tags: java, oracle, azure, oracle-xe

I am currently developing a program for my final year project in college which requires database connectivity online and offline. I have a Oracle 11g xe database setup on a Microsoft Azure Windows Server 2012 VM and a similar database on my localhost. For security reasons the database stored on the localhost must be encrypted or made secure in some other way.

Is there anyway through Oracle to keep the databases synchronized or will I have to achieve this through my program (java program with JDBC) ? Also is there anyway to secure or encrypt data stored in an Oracle 11g xe database ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, I think you want to synchronize Oracle database hosted between localhost and Azure VM.

Per my experience, the simple way is using some data synchronization tools  to do.

I recommend that you can try to use these tools below running on localhost for your needs.

1. WARTS (for Java): http://warts.sourceforge.net/
2. DBeaver (for Java): http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/docs/features/#Data_transfer_(export/import)
3. SqlSync (running on Linux): http://silvercoders.com/en/products/sqlsync/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks very much I will try them out!